# Ubuntu-Windows10 dual boot

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I am new here and i need you help in order to solve my problem.
Yesterday i decided to make partition on my laptop (HP Pavilion 15-b103 (5i-3337U/4G/500GB)) and install Ubuntu 16.10. My laptop runs windows 10. Everything was ok in installation but the problem is that i can't make dual boot..i mean to choose operating system when my laptop boots. I tried everything on goolge (disable safe mode, run repair boot on ubuntu, enable legacy mode, bios etc.) but still it boots directly to windows 10!!!
Can you please tell me how to fix it? I want to start using ubuntu but i don't want to delete windows.
PS: I have already try to find the answer here and i already applied the solutions but nothing worked :(
Thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

These are the complete steps you need to have Windows and Ubuntu on the boot menu, you will need a live disk to go into the terminal.
After it boots go into the terminal and enter the following command:
    sudo fdisk -l

This command will show you all the partitions on your HDD, you have to know which partition your Linux distro is installed on (Gparted can be a great help in that).

Use gparted to see where is Linux installed

and enter this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

then this command:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

then this command

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

then this command

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

then this command

```
update-grub
```

If the computer boots directly into Ubuntu (or whatever Linux distro you have)
go to the terminal and enter:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally reboot and you will have the grub menu with Both Linux and Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Disable the secure boot

Disable the fast startup

Disable the hibernation:

Right-click on the Start button and choose Command Prompt (Admin),type:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

and press the Enter key, exit

Boot from Ubuntu live USB

mount your root partition `sdXY`

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

mount your boot partition e,g: `sdXZ` (Fat32):

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdXZ /mnt/boot/efi
```

Mount the following partitions:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Then chroot:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Reinstall grub:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
```

Run:

```
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
```

Update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Exit the `chroot`:

```
exit
```

Unmount your partitions:

```
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt
```

Reboot